# How to return previous and next element by element from array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and i want to return the next and previous elements by a given string.
This is the array:

```
var array = [
      "11111",
      "22222",
      "343245",
      "5455",
      "34999",
      "34555",
    ];
```

The user inputs a random number, unknown number, and i have to find the next and previous elements based on the user' string.

For example the User writes: 3499
And the return must be Previous element is 5455 and next element is 34555.

Comment: look into `[].indexOf()`, that should set you in the right direction

Comment: I tried making the array to an object using the "{}" brackets and assigning keys to each element, therefore i tried returning the current value's index with this `array.indexOf(currentValue);`, but sadfly it didn't work.

Comment: please add some more examples and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to get the index of the element and get other element based on the index.

```js
var array = [
  "11111",
  "22222",
  "343245",
  "5455",
  "34999",
  "34555",
];

var ele = "34999";

var index = array.indexOf(ele);

console.log('next', array[index + 1])
console.log('prev', array[index - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "indexOf":

```
function getNextIten(num, nums){
    const idx = nums.indexOf(num)
    if (idx && idx < nums.length-1){
        return nums[idx+1]
    }
    return null
}

nums = [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10];
num = 7;
console.log(getNextIten(num ,nums)) //8
```

Or in one line like:

```
prev = nums.find((_, i, e) => num === e[i + 1]);
next = nums.find((_, i, e) => num === e[i - 1]);
```